# Awk is not tabulating the output of a text file

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk, scripting

I am trying to swap a column which match "DIC" with the first column. The file I am referring has its fields separated by tabs.

file.txt

```
NO   DIC   IC   RNDIC   FI   BO   CF
---
1    2    3    4    5    6
```

Here is the code I have so far:

```
str="DIC"

awk -F '\t' 
  ' NR == 1 {
      for (i = 2; i < NF; i++) 
      {
         if ($i == "'$str'") 
            a = i
      }
   } 

   {
      t = $1;
      $1 = $a;
      $a = t;
      print;
   }' $PWD/file.txt > $PWD/file2.txt
```

The output I want in file2.txt is: (each field is separated by tabs)

```
DIC   NO   IC   RNDIC   FI   BO   CF
---
2    1    3    4    5    6
```

Instead I am getting this: (each field is separated by a single space which is not what I want):

```
DIC NO IC RNDIC FI BO CF
---
2 1 3 4 5 6
```

Is there a way to have the output properly tabulated in file2.txt? Thanks.

Let me know if further explanation is required.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use OFS='\t` as well to have output field separator as tab

```
awk -v str="$str"
  'BEGIN {FS = OFS = "\t"}
   NR == 1 {
      for (i = 2; i < NF; i++) {
         if ($i == str) 
            a = i
      }
   }     
   {
      t = $1;
      $1 = $a;
      $a = t;
      print;
   }' $PWD/file.txt > $PWD/file2.txt
```

Comment: Thanks! Wow another silly mistake on my part. I was staring at this for 2 hours! I will accept your answer when the site permits me to. +1

Comment: I personally find it awkward to have variable declarations after the script. Other ways to write this include: `awk -F '\t' -v OFS='\t' 'script ...` or `awk 'BEGIN {FS = OFS = "\t"} rest of script...`

Comment: @glennjackman is right. Setting variables in the file name list is primarily for when you need to set variables to initial values differently for different files, otherwise setting them up front makes far more sense. In what other programming language do you look past the END of the program to find variable initializations? In this case since setting FS and OFS to the same value `BEGIN{FS=OFS="\t"}` is best for clarity, redundancy, etc.

Comment: Both Ed and Glen are right. I have corrected it now.